# EF Core SaveChangesInterceptor throws The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I have the following interceptor in EF Core 7 which is trying to remove duplicate entries of type IEnumEntity with the same Id added to the ChangeTracker. When I call SaveChanges though I still get the error `The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked` when calling this code

```
var trackedEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEnumEntity>()...
```

Why am I getting this since `base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken)` was not called yet?

```cs
public class EnumEntitySaveInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{   
   public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData,
                                                                         InterceptionResult<int> result,
                                                                         CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   {
       var context = eventData.Context;

       // Get a list of all added and modified entities grouped by their type and Id
       var trackedEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEnumEntity>()
           .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
           .GroupBy(e => new { Type = e.Entity.GetType(), Id = GetEntityId(e.Entity) });

       // Loop through each group of entities with the same Type and Id
       foreach (var group in trackedEntities)
       {
           // If there are multiple entities with the same Type and Id,
           // detach all but the first one
           var entitiesToDetach = group.Skip(1).ToList();
           foreach (var entry in entitiesToDetach)
           {
               entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
           }
       }

       return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
   }

   public override InterceptionResult<int> SavingChanges(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
   {
       .... same logic as SavingChangesAsync
   }


   private int GetEntityId(object entity)
   {
       var type = entity.GetType();
       var idProperty = type.GetProperty("Id");
       if (idProperty != null && idProperty.PropertyType == typeof(int))
       {
           return (int)idProperty.GetValue(entity);
       }
       throw new InvalidOperationException($"Entity type {type} does not have an Id property of type int.");
   }
}
```

And the stacktrace of the exception

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.NavigationCollectionChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase, IEnumerable`1 added, IEnumerable`1 removed)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.NavigationCollectionChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase, IEnumerable`1 added, IEnumerable`1 removed)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectNavigationChange(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigationBase navigationBase)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.LocalDetectChanges(InternalEntityEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.DetectChanges(IStateManager stateManager)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.TryDetectChanges()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ChangeTracker.Entries[TEntity]()
at MyProject.EntityFramework.Inteceptors.EnumEntitySaveInterceptor.SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult`1 result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Github\........
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreLoggerExtensions.SaveChangesStartingAsync(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, DbContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Analyze call stack. You cannot add to change tracker entities with the same type and Key. It should fail early. So your code has no sense.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do. Remove duplicates.

Comment: It is too late. `ChangeTracker` will throw exception exactly when you add entity. `SaveChangesInterceptor` executed later, before saving changes.

Comment: Clear that is too late but It throws exception when I call SaveChangesAsync not when I add entity. How can I intercept and remove duplicate entities then ?

Comment: Something hidden here. This code should not fail. Again show exception call stack.

Comment: Also try `ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => typeof(IEnumEntity).IsAssignableFrom(e.Metadata.ClrType));`

Comment: Added stacktrace

Comment: Try my variant how to retrieve entries. Also looks like you have did something for navigation properties.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Try remove `entry.State = EntityState.Detached;`. Also show how do you add/update data for `DbContext`

Comment: It doesn't even reach that line.

Comment: Then problem in outer code, which fill `DbContext`